# Algebraic geometry- normal schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can any one give me some intuition about analogy between normal schemes and smooth manifolds?
I do not know why having integrally closed stalks lead to being smooth.

Comment: It doesn't --- normality is weaker than nonsingularity, which is the (or one) correct analogue of smoothness.

Comment: The set of singular points of a scheme (say, of finite type over a field) is a closed subset. Normality implies (but is not equivalent) to the fact that this set has codimension at least 2. So it implies some smoothness for the variety, that is enough to have good properties in the theory of divisors for example.